Intermittent battery warning issue
2012 Dodge Grand Caravan w/ ~150K miles.

Symptoms (started ~2 years ago):

Intermittent battery warning light with "ding!" alarm.
Sometimes when the battery warning lights up, car accessories (e.g. radio head unit) will reset and other dash warning lights will temporarily appear.
Less frequently, climate control will stop for ~30 seconds while everything resets.


No loss of power for driving, steering, braking, etc. Accessories generally work fine.
I replaced the battery ~9 months ago, which didn't resolve the issue.
I installed a cheap Android head unit off Amazon ~6 years ago to replace the faulty OEM radio, so I suspected that this head unit had gone bad and was drawing too much power, causing the warnings. But when I ran the van with the head unit disconnected, I still experienced the intermittent battery warning.

Normally if a battery issue continued after a battery replacement, I would suspect a faulty alternator. But if the alternator were bad, wouldn't the battery have died by now? And wouldn't I experience other power/accessory loss? This makes me suspect something weird like a bad relay or even computer chip somewhere.
I'm selling the vehicle soon, so just wondering if it's worth it to fix this, or sell it as is. These Caravans are super roomy with the stow-n-go seats folding into the floor, making them great beater work vans for tradesmen, who might not care about the intermittent dash warnings...

I'm thinking if you are truly worried about it, I'd pull the alternator and have it checked. You can have it done at most any car parts store. The "battery" light doesn't mean there's a problem with your battery, per se, but rather that there's an issue with your charging system. When was the last time you replaced the serpentine belt? Belt slippage can cause the light to flicker. If it's worn out, it might be an issue.

@Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Not a bad idea. Someone else suggested checking the serpentine belt too. It's never been replaced, to my knowledge.

Serpentine belt should be changed every 100k, so sounds like something which needs to be done whether it's the issue or not.

Can you cause the symptoms (light, ding, reset, etc.) by monkeying around with the ignition switch? Turn it slightly this way and that while the engine is running; force it up, down, in, out, and generally abuse it to try to create these symptoms. Nothing should happen at all when you do this, so if you can create the symptoms just once, that would suggest a worn out ignition switch.

@MTA no, in fact the battery warning now seems to come on immediately upon starting the engine most times. (I wonder if it's a warning condition that the computer keeps for a certain time period to allow code reading.) Jiggling the ignition switch didn't cause the accessory reset.

@JordanRieger No, the battery warning light is not a remembered condition; it's the condition right now. It's an indication that current is flowing from the battery (discharging) rather than into it (charging), or whenever the alternator's output voltage is lower than the battery's voltage at that instant. If the serp belt is glazed or contaminated with oil and/or the belt tensioner is worn out, it slips, preventing full output voltage and the light will come on. Friction from slippage can heat up the belt and make it stickier so in time the alternator spins faster and the light goes off.

Come to think of it, I've been noticing higher-than-usual noise from the front-end, too. It's a kind of whining noise that increases with road speed, but not with engine revs. A mechanic friend listened to it with me and didn't think it sounded too serious. He checked my wheel hub/bearing assembly, and it was secure, so he assumed it was just noisy tires. But then I changed the tires, and the noise remained. So maybe that noise is the alternator and/or serpentine belt and related to the same issue as the battery warning.

Have a good look at the alternator .Run the car parked at idle with voltmeter across battery ,Expect about 14 volts now gradually turn on more accessories like headlamps etc, The voltage should not drop  if the charging system is keeping up with the draw .You should hear the engine labour a little bit due to more torque on the belt .If volts drop then check belt tension after cutting engine .If loose then tension and retest ,If volts too low then swap out alternator .If swap alternator is not available then check the slip rings for wear because this does cause intermittant operation.

My mechanic friend checked the OBD codes with me, and the car was reporting an over-voltage in the charging system. He said this likely means the voltage regulator on the alternator is faulty. Higher voltage would explain why the battery is still OK and the accessories still work, but occasionally the car resets things, perhaps as a safety precaution. I'm going to get a new alternator and have it installed with a new serpentine belt while we're at it (even though the belt did not show any overt signs of excessive wear or tension/slippage issues.)
